# Filter git log to show only commits with notes

Tags: git

How can I dump a log of my commits showing only the ones with notes of a given namespace?

Commits without notes, or notes not belonging to a given namespace should be filtered out

In the text dump I do not want just the note, also the commit info.

I have played with: show refs/notes/ and I believe the solution might be there rather than with "git log". However I am still having some problems to find the right command showing also all commits.

Comment: have you tried something with `git notes list`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git notes` will give you the id of each note and what object it applies to.  So the second column is what you want.

```
$ git notes
f5ac8874676de3029ffc8c31935644ff7c4deae0 07ca160c58cf259fe8bb5e87b9d9a7cbf8845f87
62ecfc95355587d6d1f779fcaca6e4f53d088ccc eb6c60b9dcb56219d9d882759c0bf928f6d6c3fa
```

Grab that last column using `cut` and pass them into `git show`.

```sh
[ "$(git notes)" = "" ] || git notes \
| cut -d' ' -f2 \
| xargs git show
```

To pick a specific namespace, add a `--ref=namespace` to `git notes`.

```sh
[ "$(git notes --ref=namespace)" = "" ] || git notes --ref=namespace \
| cut -d' ' -f2 
| xargs git show
```

The initial test, `[...]`,  prevents a slight problem: `git show` will show the current checkout if passed no arguments.
So if there's no notes you're going to get misleading output.  With the initial test that's not
a problem: if the test fails, i.e., if there's no notes, then `git show` won't be called.

Comment: The `-r` flag (or `--no-run-if-empty`) will fix the "slight problem" in case of GNU `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a test to Schwern answer:

```
[ "$(git notes)" = "" ] || git notes \
| cut -d' ' -f2 \
| xargs git show
```

or to pick up a particular namespace:

```
[ "$(git notes --ref=namespace)" = "" ] || git notes --ref=namespace \
| cut -d' ' -f2 \
| xargs git show
```

Then, if the initial test [...] fails, i.e., if there's no notes, ***git show*** won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `git log`-style report of only the commits with attached notes, then you can use the `--no-walk` argument to tell `git log` to limit the report the only the commits listed on the command line.  e.g.,

```
git notes list \
| cut -d' ' -f2 \
| xargs --no-run-if-empty git log --no-walk=sorted
```

I added `--no-walk=sorted` to order the output by commit time, rather than the arbitrary order output by `git notes`.

You can of course add any of the other `git log` options to format the output as you prefer.